# How to post form login using jsoup in andorid?

Tags: java, android, authentication, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to login in [here](https://erp.cbit.org.in/?__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTExMDk3MjkwOA9kFgICAQ9kFgICBQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGRkApSadXV8hBd7qi9M9MQf24gQFo1JDdpv3rqIRSVoR5Y%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=C2EE9ABB&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAUo8HF9hHYWKGGF3Et0JGNxBjpuGLkudYNkCAonVyADt%2B5PVNfdHmla7NuBu7%2FwrMNjemWCTRgEB59HPczIGVNwgWOkgugWB5Cq9dYD7toQNEwZfb2PCk9YCZQ7UhXsjSWufILYgZp8zPh7f7XDtu2a&txtUserName=160117737089&btnNext=Next)

[image: College Website]

## Below is HTML File:

[image]

I want to take Password in txtPassword field and click on btnSubmit

or else fetch the post request fetch code from network

[image]

## I'm trying this code:

private class Content extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            //Connect to the website

            String url="https://erp.cbit.org.in/?__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTExMDk3MjkwOA9kFgICAQ9kFgICBQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGRkApSadXV8hBd7qi9M9MQf24gQFo1JDdpv3rqIRSVoR5Y%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=C2EE9ABB&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAUo8HF9hHYWKGGF3Et0JGNxBjpuGLkudYNkCAonVyADt%2B5PVNfdHmla7NuBu7%2FwrMNjemWCTRgEB59HPczIGVNwgWOkgugWB5Cq9dYD7toQNEwZfb2PCk9YCZQ7UhXsjSWufILYgZp8zPh7f7XDtu2a&txtUserName=160117737089&btnNext=Next";

            Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();

            Document document= Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0")
                    .data("cookieexists", "false")
                    .data("txtPassword","8055")
                    .data("btnSubmit","Submit")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .post();

            Element attendance = document.getElementById("ctl00_cpStud_lblTotalPercentage");
            at=attendance.text();
            at=at.replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]","");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, at, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

After the execution document post() method is returning html code of the current page i.e. url page not the result page.

Comment: try using Jsoup to login websites  http://joelmin.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html

Comment: The website I want to retrieve information is very outdated and has two separate webpages for username and password. I'll use the link as reference.

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem I referred the blog, I dont have form data, session url, authenticity_token in the network heads of website.

Comment: You DO have `viewstate`, `eventvalidation` etc. in the post request. Find them the same way you've found that the password field is called `txtPassword` and not some other name.

Comment: After finding those how to connect to the page?